# Tokbox session methods inaccessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, opentok, tokbox

I am getting a javascript object which contains method list but I am not able to access method.
I am integrating tokbox api and i want to call unpublish function when user wants to disconnect the stream.
Please find attached image of my object and whole function list. Please give me solutions as soon as possible.[image: tokbox object]

Comment: very nice question i am also facing same type of problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem from the screenshot attached. The `session.unpublish(publisher)` method should work as expected. If it is not, can you please show what the errors or the bad behavior look like? Are you passing in the Publisher object? Also be aware that just because you unpublish, does not mean the video element on the page will disappear, for that you must call `publisher.destroy()`. Lastly, the most simple solution would just be to call `session.disconnect()` and that will automatically clean up by unpublishing and destroying the publisher.

I do see another error related to a parameter you passed to either `OT.initPublisher(element, properties, completionHandler)`, `session.publish(element, properties, completionHandler)`, or `session.subscribe(stream, element, properties, completionHandler)`. In one of those, as the `element` parameter, you are passing a reference to `window` rather than a valid element from the page. You might also have intended to use a String that matches the `id` attribute of an element on the page. Please fix that.